# Como puedo integrar Pygame y PyQt4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

Estoy usando Python 2.7 y Ubuntu 14.04.

Me encuentro intentando hacer [esto](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.init) para poder insertar mi ventana pygame en mi ventana PyQt4.

> **En algunas plataformas es posible incrustar el display de pygame en una ventana existente. Para hacerlo la variable de entorno SDL_WINDOWID debe contener un string con el id de la ventana destino. Esta variable es chequeada cuando el display de pygame es inicializado.**

Este es mi codigo:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import os
import subprocess
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
    MainWindow.setFixedSize(800, 600)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    self.iniMap()

def iniMap(self):
    command = "xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW"
    output = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", command], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    activeWindowID = str(output.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8").strip().split()[-1])
    os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = activeWindowID
    import pygame
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((565, 437), pygame.NOFRAME)

class frmMain(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(frmMain, self).__init__(parent, flags=QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = frmMain()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Pero esto no funciona, solo muestra mi ventana PyQt. No se si lo que estoy haciendo esta mal, o si directamente pygame no puede ser integrado con PyQt.

¿Qué debería hacer para poder incrustar mi pygame en `frmMain`?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Me encontré con algo parecido y lo solucioné con:

```python
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (x,y)
```

Antes del `pygame.init`, juega dando valores a `x` e `y` para ajustar a tu ventana.

No es elegante pero funciona :)